# ¿Cómo aplicar una url usando Blade Laravel en javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, json, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy usando typehead mezclado con prefecth para el auto completar de un campo llamado rut, al minuto de solicitar información a un archivo JSON si uso la ruta llamándola de la siguiente forma:

**prefetch: '/providers/json'**

No me arroja ningún inconveniente, mientras que si trato de respetar la sintaxis de blade laravel llamando a la url de la siguiente forma:

**prefetch: '{{url('/providers/json')}}'**

No interactuá con la ruta, la cual está definida dentro de mi archivo web.php

Este es el código de la parte de JavaScript:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var providers = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

            prefetch: '{{url('/providers/json')}}'
        });

        $('#rut').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 3
        },
        {
            name: 'providers',
            source: providers
        })
    });
</script>
```

Nota: Uso la versión de laravel 5.6

Comment: ¿confirmaste que blade esté escribiendo correctamente la ruta en el html?

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo confirmar eso?, actualmente veo si me aparece el llamado des de las herramientas de firefox.

Comment: Devtools del navegador.

Comment: Así es, también imprimí la url de la siguiente forma: {!!url('/providers/json')!!} para ver la url completa y contrastarla con la que esta en web.php y ambas son iguales, el problema se me genera cuando la pido desde el script

Comment: intenta agregar esto en tu primera linea del script alert('{{url('/providers/json')}}'); y comprueba que te dice

Comment: Intenta asignarle la url a una variable fuera del providers y luego asignala.

Comment: Me muestra la url bien, probare lo de la variable

Comment: Mismo resultado al pasar la url a una variable

Comment: También cree la variable fuera del providers y nada. Puedo poner la url manualmente y me la toma pero no es la idea

Comment: comprueba que no estes usando csrf_token o que te este faltando en el ajax https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf

Comment: Quite el @csrf del form y el resultado es el mismo, con respecto al ajax, ¿qué le puede falta? O.o

Comment: esto puede ir a un chat, los comentarios son muchos.

Comment: Pero es muy raro, esto no es más que un simple texto impreso con el html, lo cual carga obviamente antes de JavaScript. ¿has probado con otros navegadores?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente en el head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

en el `$(document).ready`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Alternativamente podes excluir ciertas rutas del middleware que chequea el `csrf` (`VerifyCsrfToken`)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: Probé tu solución y mismo resultado, no me toma la url del JSON.

Comment: f12 pestaña network filtrar por xhr click sobre la peticion que dice?

Comment: Probé y el usar la sintaxis de blade no me llama a la url

Answer (score 0):

Sé que el post ya tiene tiempo.
Yo lo hago de ésta forma:

```
var prefetch_url = '{{ url("provider/json") }}'
```

Para saber el valor que te arroja javascript puedes agregar después abajo:

`console.log(prefetch_url) // si ya quedó arreglado, bórrame`

Luego  abre la consola de chrome o mozilla, guarda cambios, recarga y te debe salir la respuesta.

Aparte la consola te va notificar de cualquier otro error que haya (un 404, una variable no definida) o lo que esté mal.